# How to wait while parallelStreams are executing?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

So, let's deal now. I have Parser class where I can get links from html. I've used Jsoup to get links and then I want to add this links to List. I'm using StreamAPI to proceed that. 
Look at the following code fragment:

```
public static List<Link> getLinksFromURL(String URL) {
    List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();
    Elements elements = selectElements(URL, "a[href]");
    elements.parallelStream().forEach((Parser) -> addLink(links, elements.attr("href")));
    return links;
}
```

It works. But what am I dealing with? When I tested this method I notice that streams execution may be finish for a while. And I can get wrong data in my test class. E.g. I check List size. During debuging all is fine. But in runtime I get few elements instead of all links because streams haven't been executed yet. 
Simple test. But size()==3 or less sometime:

```
@Test
public void getLinksFromURLTest() {
    Assert.assertTrue(Parser.getLinksFromURL("testLinks").size()==4);
}
```

**And my question is** how I can wait while this streams are executing? I need to get all links :)

*Small notice: I get html from local html that represent on Spark server that I launch for tests.*

P.S.: if I've not written understandable, please, let me know and I add explanations.

I'll be so thankful if you help me. 
Good luck everyone! :)

Update: 
addLink method

```
private static void addLink(List<Link> links, String URL) {
    if (!URL.isEmpty() && isLink(URL) && !hasSameLink(links, URL)){
        links.add(new Link(URL));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `addLink()` method.

Comment: @shmosel  I added code

Comment: @shmosel I think that I can use just stream()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a mistake in your `forEach()` call. For each element, you're calling `Elements.attr()` on the `elements` variable instead of `Element.attr()` on the current item. You probably meant to do something like this:

```
forEach(element -> addLink(links, element.attr("href")))
```

Regardless, your code is not thread safe. You can't have multiple threads writing to a regular `ArrayList` without some form of synchronization (which would likely kill the benefit of parallelization). That's also the likely reason why you're seeing inconsistent results in your testing. You should either use a thread-safe collection or just a stick with a sequential iteration.

Alternatively, you may be able to convert all of your logic to a stream pipeline and use a collector instead:

```
return elements.parallelStream()
        .filter(url -> !url.isEmpty())
        .filter(url -> isLink(url))
        .distinct()
        .map(Link::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wow, it looks nice :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: What if I use stream() instead of parallelStream() ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИгнатик That's probably fine. You shouldn't assume parallel is always faster. And if you're sticking with your original approach, you don't even need to stream. Just call `elements.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), it is up to you to synchronise the code. You could initialise a [`CountdownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with the number of elements, then await it in the main thread.